# VueJS not updating view after using $set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to update a list of products with an editable quantity, which updates and changes a row-wise total of product prices. Please see my code below -

```
<template>
    <div>
        <product-search-bar :product_search_route="product_search_route" />

        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Qty.</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(product, index) in product_list">
                <td>
                    {{ index + 1 }}
                    <input type="hidden" :name="'order_items[' + index + '][id]'" :value="product.id" />
                </td>
                <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" :name="'order_items[' + index + '][qty]'" @change="product_quantity_changed($event, product)" />
                </td>
                <td>{{ product.purchase_currency }} {{ product.total_price }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'form-purchase-order-items',
        props: [
            'product_search_route',
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                product_list: []
            };
        },
        mounted() {
        },
        methods: {
            /**
             *
             * @param product
             */
            product_added(product)
            {
                product.quantity = 1;
                product.total_price = product.supplier.purchase_price;

                if (!this.product_list.find((v) => { return v.id == product.id }))
                    this.product_list.push(product);
            },

            /**
             *
             * @param product
             */
            product_quantity_changed(e, product)
            {
                var quantity = Number(e.target.value);
                this.$set(product, 'quantity', quantity);
                this.$set(product, 'total_price', (quantity * product.supplier.purchase_price));
            }
        },
        watch: {
        }
    }
</script>
```

The price total does update correctly, seen through Vue DevTools, however, the column `<td>{{ product.purchase_currency }} {{ product.total_price }}</td>` doesn't reflect the changes made. I've read the documentation and I think this is something that isn't mentioned there.

Edit:

The two members `quantity` and `total_price` are being created after the object is received in the `product_added(product)` callback. This probably makes them non-reactive members of the object.

Comment: Try not passing `product` into @change, instead just pass the `index` then in method use `$set` on `this.product_list[index]` and see if this works?

Comment: @Zlatev I've tried this too, the result is identical to the current code.

Comment: Setting a v-for :key (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) is also worth a try

Comment: I prepared jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/201784/ the value changed but you need to remove focus from input to fire change handler, I suggest to use `input` event it will be more informative.

Comment: `$set` only work on vue data ! Your product is not vue data ! It is temp array data @SagunKho

Answer (score 2):

try `@input` instead of `@change` in following html code:

```
<input type="number" :name="'order_items[' + index + '][qty]'" @change="product_quantity_changed($event, product)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by making `quantity` and `total_price` reactive members.

```
        product_added(product)
        {
            this.$set(product, 'quantity', 1);
            this.$set(product, 'total_purchase_price', product.supplier.purchase_price);

            if (!this.product_list.find((v) => { return v.id == product.id }))
                this.product_list.push(product);
        },
```